# R doMPI installation not working - requires building from source?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-caret

I'm trying to install the doMPI package in R.
Apparently there are no binaries available for the 3.x version?
Do i need to build it from source?

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doMPI/
<>

The goal is to run parallel processing with caret on a windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

CRAN doesn't build binaries of doMPI for Mac OS X or Windows because it depends on the Rmpi package, and it doesn't build binaries for Rmpi because it depends on MPI libraries which don't come by default on those platforms. Some people have suggested that I declare Rmpi to be a *suggested* package to work-around this issue, but in fact, doMPI really does depend on Rmpi, so it always seemed like an odd thing to do. The way I see it, if you're able to build Rmpi from source, you'll have no trouble building doMPI from source.

So yes, you have to build it from source, but the bigger problem is to build Rmpi from source, unless you're using a Linux distribution like Debian that distributes both Rmpi and doMPI as binary deb packages.

But if you just want to run caret in parallel on a Windows machine, the normal solution is to use the doParallel package using a PSOCK cluster. People have trouble with that as well, but at least installation of the packages is easy since there are binary packages available for doParallel on CRAN.

Comment: Thank you. However, i am facing a strange problem that led to trying Rmpi. I previously used doSNOW which ran rather smoothly with caret. I then updated my R and caret versions - and the two don't seem to "work" with each other anymore, in the sense that CPU/RAM usage seems to be fully utilized, but the actual performance is in line with non-parallel implementation. And, following your advice, trying doParallel creates the same issue. Any idea what to do and whether the package updates could have caused this change?

Comment: @topepo - could an update in caret packages create some clash with doX packages?

Comment: @mrquestion I don't know why you might be seeing decreased parallel performance in caret. I'm not surprised that doParallel worked no better than doSNOW since they are so similar. I suggest that you try to reproduce the better performance, and then determine the change that causes the performance to degrade (caret, doSNOW, R, OS, whatever). There's a very good chance that switching to doMPI won't help.